# MySQL remove specific number from list

Tags: mysql

I've got a database that has the following structure:

```
+----+----+-------------------+---------------+
| id | by | name              | list          |
+----+----+-------------------+---------------+
|  1 |  1 | FirstName         | 12,6,5,3,2,66 |
+----+----+-------------------+---------------+
|  2 |  1 | SecondName        | 6,3,5         |
+----+----+-------------------+---------------+
```

What I need to do is to remove a certain number from the `list` column, for example the "6" number (the `table` might have thousands of rows that contain a particular list id that I would need to remove).

I've tried the following query that almost works, it can remove the '6' entry, but it would also strip off the 66 and can leave an empty list element (e.g: ,,3,2):

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `list` =
REPLACE (
    `list`,
    '6',
    '' )
WHERE
    find_in_set('6', list);
```

Sadly I won't be able to use any external libraries for MySQL (like preg_replace), nor restructure the database, is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Phil have your read the whole post? I clearly said that I cannot restructure the database.

Comment: Yes I did and I've asked you why you cannot do that

Comment: But why bother with the database at all?

Comment: @Strawberry because that what I was asked to do.

Comment: But you're not taking advantage of the one thing that relational databases are really good at :-(

Comment: @Strawberry Sadly that's not up to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't restructure and need to live with this abomination, I seriously recommend you do not take this job.

That said, you need to discriminate 3 cases:

- 6 at the beginning,
- 6 at the end
- 6 in the middle

So you will need three queries

```
UPDATE `table` SET `list`=RIGHT(`list`,CHAR_LENGTH(`list`)-2) WHERE `list` LIKE '6,%';
UPDATE `table` SET `list`=LEFT(`list`,CHAR_LENGTH(`list`)-2) WHERE `list` LIKE '%,6';
UPDATE `table` SET `list`=REPLACE(`list`,',6,','') WHERE `list` LIKE '%,6,%';
```

Mind the constant `2` - it is only valid for a single digit. To make this universal use `CHAR_LENGTH("6")+1`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this with one update statement.  The blasphemous idea is to replace the commas with spaces, so you can use `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`:

```
update table t
    set list = replace(ltrim(rtrim(replace(concat(' ', replace(list, ',', ' '), ' '), ' 6 ', ' '))), ' ', ',')
    where find_in_set('6', list) > 0;
```

The steps are:

1. Replaces the commas in the list with spaces.
2. Add a space to the beginning and end of the list.
3. Replace `' 6 '` with a space.  This removes the element wherever it is in the list.
4. Use `ltrim()` and `rtrim()` to remove spaces at the beginning and end of the string.
5. Replace the spaces back with commas.